# How to implement .click() for <a> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I am trying to change the text of an  link tag when it is clicked using jquery. The trick is that the  tag is created with jquery and does not exist on page load.

here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arcco96/hjo3kb4b/4/

the jquery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#round-button").click(function () {

    // do something
    $("#button-text").text("new text");

});

});
```

The a tag looks like this: `<a class="round-button" id="round-button" href="#">
      <p id="button-text">Blah!</p></a>`

For some reason the code does not work. It works on other elements such as a button and even other  elements but on the "#roud-button" in particular it does not.

I have heard this is a commonish problem but when i tried to implement some of the usual solutions it did not work.

Any thoughts?

thanks

Comment: The fiddle does not have any <a> element.

Comment: The element doesn't exist when you run the code is why

Comment: oh yeah sorry I'm working on this for a friend. The <a> is created with query. If the tag isn't there when the document loads with the onclick event register with the javascript. I apologize if this isn't the lingo I'm not that web-language savvy.

Comment: Where is #roud-button and #button-text in your jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are creating the button dynamically, jQuery isn't able to wire up the click handler on the `$.ready` because it doesn't exist yet.

What you can do is use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind the handler, which will work when the button is added to the document:

```
$("#container").on('click', "#round-button",  function () {
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hjo3kb4b/6/)

Answer (score 1):

check code on following link
http://jsfiddle.net/hjo3kb4b/5/

$("#round-button").click(function () {

```
// do something
$("#button-text").html("new text");
```

});

This should be defined where button is inserted on page .. you called this script on document load.